# show UIAlertController outside of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have trouble to display my UIAlertController because I'm trying to show it in a Class which is not an ViewController.

I already tried adding it:

```
 var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Which is not working...
I didn't find any solution that worked for me yet.

Comment: You're class which is not a UIViewController now is partly untestable. Consider adding a delegate or a block based callback to display the alert on the view controller that's using this class.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I wrote this `extension` over `UIAlertController` to bring back `show()`.
It uses recursion to find the current top view controller:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    
    func show() {
        present(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func present(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            presentFromController(controller: rootVC, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
    
    private func presentFromController(controller: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if 
            let navVC = controller as? UINavigationController,
            let visibleVC = navVC.visibleViewController
        {
            presentFromController(controller: visibleVC, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        } else if
            let tabVC = controller as? UITabBarController,
            let selectedVC = tabVC.selectedViewController
        {
            presentFromController(controller: selectedVC, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        } else if let presented = controller.presentedViewController {
            presentFromController(controller: presented, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        } else {
            controller.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion);    
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's as easy as:

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.show()
```

Comment: Glad it works for you, I have been using it with many VC scenarios (modal vc on a nav stack inside a tab bar controller etc.), please let me know if theres a situation where this doesn't work...

Comment: SharedApplication cannot be used in an App Extension.

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where the key view controller is already presenting something modally. I had to add another check  `if let presented = controller.presentedViewController { presentFromController(controller: presented, animated: animated, completion: completion) } else { controller.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)  }`

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController?.presentViewController(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper function that you call from the current view controller and pass the current view controller as a parameter:

```
func showAlertInVC(
  viewController: UIViewController, 
  title: String, 
message: String)
{
  //Code to create an alert controller and display it in viewController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you solution is not working it probably because of there is no window at that moment. I had the same problem when I was trying to show alert view in `application:DidFinishLoadingWithOptions` method. In this case my solution was to check if root view controller is available, and if it's not, then add notification for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
                object: nil,
                queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                    (_) in
                        //show your alert by using root view controller
                        //remove self from observing
                    }
        }
```