# Show custom UI feedback for Action extension

Tags: ios, swift

I want to build an Action extension but avoid showing the system compose view controller that animates via modal on top of the screen. When the action is finished, I want to present the user with a custom toast/alert view indicating that the action has been finished. Is it possible to use a custom animation and view for feedback for an Action extension without using the native compose view controller?

Comment: Why not present the alert on top of the modal view, and then dismiss the modal view when the alert is dismissed?

Comment: Well in most cases the amount of time between tapping the action and displaying feedback that the action is complete isn't that long so it would seem pretty jarring to see this modal pop up and down right away if I can avoid it.

Comment: Wait, you don't want the modal view at all? You may want to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052299/show-uialertcontroller-outside-of-viewcontroller) code, and call the `show()` method in `viewWillAppear()` and then call `self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems(self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)`.

Comment: @StephanLeroux did you find a solution?

Comment: @Lukas I haven't revisited this question in a long time and stopped looking for a solution a while back. If you've found something let me know!